# confusion regarding event handling in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. while practicing i encounter a code regarding event handling. Here is the code

```
//This generic event handler creates an object called eventHandler
var etHandler = {};

if (document.addEventListener) {

    //eventHandler object has two methods added to it, add()and remove(),
    etHandler.add = function(element, eventType, eventFunction) {

        /**
         * The add method in each model determines whether the event type is a load event, meaning that
         *  the function needs to be executed on page load.
         */
        if (eventType == "load") {

            .......

        }
    };// end of eventHandler.add = function()

    etHandler.remove = function(element, eventType, eventFunction) {

        element.detachEvent("on" + eventType, eventFunction);

    }; //end of  etHandler.remove = function()
}

function sendAlert() {

    alert("Hello");

} //end of sendAlert()

function startTimer() {

    var timerID = window.setTimeout(sendAlert,3000);

}//end of startTimer()

var mainBody = document.getElementById("mainBody");

etHandler.add(mainBody, "load", function() {

                                startTimer();

                            }
             );
```

The questions that i want to ask are this. We create an empty object.`var etHandler = {};`. It's fine. Then we are checking condition `if (document.addEventListener) {}`. we didn't add any event listener to the document, but this condition is true. Why this condition is returning true?
Then we write `etHandler.add = function(element, eventType, eventFunction) {}`. Why we are writing `etHandler.add`? etHandler object has no property, when we created it. It's a null object. If we create etHandler like this

```
var etHandler = {

    add: function() {

    },

    remove: function(){

    }
};
```

Then we can write `etHandler.add`. The same question is for etHandler.remove also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `if (document.addEventListener)` is checking whether the browser supports this method. It is checking to see whether it exists on the document object. This is called feature detection and is frequently used to detect differences between browsers.

The call `etHandler.add = function(element, eventType, eventFunction)` defines the `add` method and creates it simultaneously. It is basically the same as in your example.

Comment: HHmm i read about feature detection, but in the book, it was written that use `typeof` for feature detection, Like **To test for the existence of the getElementById() method, which indicates
that the browser supports the more advanced DOM interface, you might use this code:**
`if (typeof document.getElementById != "undefined") {
alert("getelembyid is supported"); } else { alert("no getelembyid support"); }`. It was also written **You may be tempted to skip the use of typeof within the test, and you may see examples on
the web where a feature test looks like this:**  continue....

Comment: `if(document.getElementById) { ... }`. **Unfortunately, this method of feature testing isn’t as reliable as the typeof test. The problem
is that the shorter syntax runs the method. When you omit typeof, the method or property
being tested might return 0 or false by default, which makes the test fail; in other words, it
appears that the browser doesn’t support that method or property—when it actually does.
Therefore, testing using typeof is safer and more reliable.**. That's why i counfused...

Comment: You also said **The call `etHandler.add = function(element, eventType, eventFunction)` defines the add method and creates it simultaneously. It is basically the same as in your example.** You mean to say behind the scenes, javascript creates something like this? `var etHandler = { add: function() {},remove: function(){}};` Is it?

Comment: @Basit - You already seem to know the answer to your question! Honestly I don't see people use typeOf for feature detection. The fact that not using typeOf causes the method to run, and that this may return zero or false tells me that the method exists, which is the whole point isn't it?

Comment: @Basit - Yes, something like that. Open your debugger and run this fiddle. Then call each object in console. You can see that they are identical. http://jsfiddle.net/d49nW/

Comment: No i didn't no the answer. If i knew it is feature detection, then i asked only about object question. when you said that this is feature detection, then it's come to mind, that i have already read about it. Anyways thank you very much :). Now i know what is going in the code:).